# Receiving log4net messages sent by a TraceAppender in another application

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-appender

I am writing a Windows service and a system tray application to control it. In my service, I have a lot of log4net logging statements. I would like to show these messages in a window that can be opened from the systray application and started experimenting with the log4net TraceAppender. I also added a custom TraceListener to my systray application. Unfortunately, I don't see any messages coming in in the systray application. I have to admit I am not sure it is even possible to receive these messages in another application.

In my service I added the following lines to my log4net.xml:

```
<appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
  <immediateFlush value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

I am also using a file appender, so in the root section I have these lines:

```
<root>
  <level value="WARN" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="TraceAppender" />
</root>
```

Note that the messages arrive in the logfile just fine.

In the systray app, I added the following class:

```
class TextBoxTraceListener : TraceListener
{
    private static TextBox _target;
    private StringSendDelegate _invokeWrite;

    public TextBoxTraceListener()
    {
    }

    public TextBoxTraceListener(TextBox target)
    {
        _target = target;
        _invokeWrite = new StringSendDelegate(SendString);
    }

    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        if (_target != null)
        {
            _target.Invoke(_invokeWrite, new object[] { message });
        }
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        if (_target != null)
        {
            _target.Invoke(_invokeWrite, new object[]
            { message + Environment.NewLine });
        }
    }

    private delegate void StringSendDelegate(string message);
    private void SendString(string message)
    {
        // No need to lock text box as this function will only 
        // ever be executed from the UI thread
        _target.Text += message;
    }
}
```

I added the constructor without arguments because I got an exception that no constructor could be found.

The code for my dialog class (WinForms) is this:

```
public partial class LogWatcherForm : Form
{
    TextBoxTraceListener _textBoxListener;

    public LogWatcherForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void LogWatcherForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _textBoxListener = new TextBoxTraceListener(logTextBox);
        Trace.Listeners.Add((TraceListener)_textBoxListener);
    }
}
```

And finally, the app.config of the systray app contains:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
    <listeners>
      <add name="myListener" type="Cordis.ServiceSysTray.TextBoxTraceListener,ServiceSysTray"/>
      <remove name="Default" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

I hope that someone can point me in the right direction to get this working. Can this be made to work using a TraceAppender?

Answer (score 0):

You have two processes. You performing Trace.WriteLine in the Windows Service using log4net and TraceAppender. In your second process, the application running in the system tray, you are listening via a custom TraceListener.

Trace.WriteLine is not broadcast so all processes can receive it. The way to fix your code is in the system tray application, add a FileSystemWatcher the monitors the log file generated by the Windows Service process. Each time the log file is updated, read the new values into system tray application and display them. When you open the log file, make sure you do not use exclusively file access.